# When does the EM for Gaussian mixture model has one of the Gaussian diminish to exactly one point and have zero variance?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, mixed-model, gaussian-mixture-distribution, expectation-maximization

I had implemented the EM algorithm for mixture models as follows:

For the **E-step** I compute the soft-counts of assigning each point $x^{(t)} \in Data_n$ to an individual cluster $j \in \{1, ..., K \}$ (by the posterior):

$$P(j | x^{(t)}) = \frac{\hat p(j) N( x^{(t)} ; \hat \mu^{(j)} , \hat \sigma^2_jI)}{\sum^{K}_{j=1} \hat p(j) N( x^{(t)} ; \hat \mu^{(j)}, \hat \sigma^2_k I ) } $$

For the **M-step** we re-compute the parameters of our model given the fixed posterior (i.e. given the soft assignments of each point to each cluster):

$$ \hat p_j = \frac{\sum^{n}_{t=1} p(j | x^{(t)}) }{n}$$

$$ \hat \mu^{(j)} = \frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{t=1} p(j | x^{(t)}) x^{(t)}$$

$$ \sigma^2_{j} = \frac{1}{dn} \sum^{n}_{t=1} p(j | x^{(t)}) \| x^{(t)} - \mu^{(j)} \|^2$$

Assuming that the above algorithm is implemented correctly, when exactly does the situation where one of the mixture components converges such that its mean is some data point $x^{(t)}$ and the standard deviation converges to zero i.e. $\sigma^2_j = 0$? Does there exist some data set such that the above scenario is possible or is it impossible if the algorithm is implemented correctly? The issue I have is that intuitively, since the exponential always is non-zero everywhere (except when there is a weird spike because of zero std) and because every data point has a soft-assignment to every cluster, it seems to me that conceptually, the scenario I am worried about should not be theoretically possible for a correct implementation of this EM algorithm. Am I correct? or can it actually happen in theory (and practice?)?

Comment: If you use as starting value $\mu_1^{(0)}=x_1$, $\sigma_1^{(0)}=0$ and $p_1^{(0)}>0$, EM will produce this solution at each iteration.

Comment: If you have some ties in your data this could happen.

Comment: It would be interesting to characterize the basins of convergence to the degenerate "solution"

Answer (score 3):

The EM algorithm is really just an iterative approximation to true Maximum Likelihood Estimation. Even if implemented correctly,

- as per Xi'an's comment, it is sensitive to starting conditions, though this can be fought by adding a constraint on the variances of the Gaussians, to ensure they don't get "narrow";
- it may only find a local maximum rather than a global one.

In practice, one often runs the EM procedure several times, with different starting conditions, to avoid mistaking a local optimum for a global one.

I think this is a good opportunity to highlight a passage by the late great [MacKay](http://www.inference.org.uk/itprnn/), who uses this particular corner case to attack the principle of MLE in general:

> [image]
>
> KABOOM!
>
> Soft K-means can blow up. Put one cluster exactly on one data
>   point and let its variance go to zero - you can obtain an arbitrarily
>   large likelihood! Maximum likelihood methods can break down by
>   finding highly tuned models that fit part of the data perfectly.
>   This phenomenon is known as overfitting. The reason we are not
>   interested in these solutions with enormous likelihood is this: sure,
>   these parameter-settings may have enormous posterior probability
>   density, but the density is large over only a very small volume of
>   parameter space. So the probability mass associated with these
>   likelihood spikes is usually tiny.
>
> We conclude that maximum likelihood methods are not a satisfactory
>   general solution to data-modelling problems: the likelihood may be
>   infinitely large at certain parameter settings. Even if the
>   likelihood does not have infinitely large spikes, the maximum of the
>   likelihood is often unrepresentative, in high dimensional problems.
>
> Even in low-dimensional problems, maximum likelihood solutions can be
>   unrepresentative. As you may know from basic statistics, the maximum
>   likelihood estimator (22.15) for a Gaussian's standard deviation is a
>   biased estimator, a topic that we'll take up in Chapter 24.

(Note that what he calls "soft k-means" is just EM.)

Comment: Tukey called models where this cannot occur *bland* or *hornless*, cited in "Data Analysis and
Approximate Models",  by  Laurie Davies.

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood maximization in the mixtures model is an issue in general. Some components cover most of the points while the rest sits on some points and runs to infinity. This is quite natural, indeed: this runs the likelihood to infinity (multiplication of some constants and some infinities). The situation can be avoided by using variational bayesian inference, implemented here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35362-variational-bayesian-inference-for-gaussian-mixture-model and explained here: http://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/~csatol/gep_tan/Bishop-CUED-2006.pdf - see slide 42.

Comment: I wonder why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

> The issue I have is that intuitively, since the exponential always is non-zero everywhere (except when there is a weird spike because of zero std) and because every data point has a soft-assignment to every cluster, it seems to me that conceptually, the scenario I am worried about should not be theoretically possible for a correct implementation of this EM algorithm. Am I correct? or can it actually happen in theory (and practice?)?

It can, both in theory and in practise.

The theoretical case Xi'an has covered in the comment below your answer, though it requires quite a specific initialisation of the parameters. More generally, consider the case where one of the mixture components assigns a very high soft count to a single sample, and a very low (but non zero) soft count to all others, and that due to the geometry of the samples this situation worsens with each iteration. As the algorithm progresses, although the variance will never reach zero, it will *tend towards* zero, and generate a big spike in your density estimate. Chances are, this not accurately approximate the distribution your samples were drawn from.

In practise, the above applies, but you also have the problem of floats/doubles only being finite precision. This can cause some of the soft counts of samples distant from the mixture component, and/or the variance parameter itself, to get rounded down to zero.

Answer (score 0):

If one attribute is *constant*, then this happens all the time.

write your program such that it can handle this.

Comment: wat do u mean by attribute?

Comment: A variate, assuming that you are doing multivariate EM. Otherwise, just assume constant data overall.